# Help in proof of $\frac{\partial(u,v)}{\partial(x,y)}.\frac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial(u,v)} = 1$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, jacobian

The following is a proof of
$$\frac{\partial(u,v)}{\partial(x,y)}.\frac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial(u,v)} = 1$$
[image: Jacobian proof]

In the above proof, I cannot understand why  $\frac{\partial u}{\partial v} = 0$ and $\frac{\partial v}{\partial u} = 0$. Since, $u$ and $v$ are independent variables, $\frac{\partial v}{\partial u}$ and $\frac{\partial u}{\partial v}$ seem to have no meaning.
$ $ $ $ $ $

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your book's exposition is a little confusing, since it has $x, y, u, v$ being used as both variables and functions.

To make it clearer, I will try to re-derive the result using $x, y, u, v$ as variables and $X, Y, U, V$ as functions.

Suppose we have the functions $U(x, y), V(x, y), X(u, v), Y(u, v)$ such that the following relations hold:

$$X(U(x, y), V(x, y)) = x$$  $$Y(U(x, y), V(x, y)) = y$$
$$U(X(u, v), Y(u, v)) = u$$ $$V(X(u, v), Y(u, v)) = u$$

These are exactly the conditions that hold when the functions $U, V, X, Y$ specify two alternate coordinate systems. Here is a diagram of the situation [image: coordinate transform diagram] where the action of $X,Y$ on points $u,v$ is depicted as a black arrow and the action of $U,V$ on points $x,y$ is depicted as a purple arrow.

Now the expressions $\partial[X|Y|U|V]/\partial[x|y|u|v]$ will make sense for all choices of "numerator" and "denominator" where the functions $X, Y, U, V$ must do double duty. In the expressions $\partial X/\partial x$ and $\partial X/\partial y$, the function $X$ stands for $X(U(x,y), V(x,y))$, and in the expressions $\partial X/\partial u$ and $\partial X/\partial v$, $X$ stands for $X(u,v)$.

Taking derivative of the first relation with respect to $x$ and applying the chain rule, you will arrive at $d_1X (U(x,y), V(x,y)) d_1U(x, y) + d_2X (U(x, y), V(x,y)) d_1V(x,y) = 1$ where $d_i$ means derivative with respect to the $i^{th}$ coordinate.

Writing this in the more terse and implicit notation we will get $\partial X/\partial u \, \partial U/\partial x + \partial X/ \partial v \, \partial V/\partial x = 1$.

Writing it even more confusingly, we get your book's presentation
$\partial x/\partial u \, \partial u/\partial x + \partial x/\partial v \, \partial v/\partial x = 1$.

It should be straightforward applications of the chain rule to verify the other 3 equations.

**Alternatively, a one liner proof:**
In general if you have two functions $A : S_1 \subset \mathbb R^n \rightarrow S_2 \subset \mathbb R^n$, $B : S_2 \subset \mathbb R^n \rightarrow S_1 \subset \mathbb R^n$ such that $A(B(x)) = x$ and $B(A(x)) = x$ for all $x \in S_2, S_1$ respectively.

We have immediately $A'(B(x))B'(x) = I$ by the [higher dimensional chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule#Higher_dimensions).

Comment: In the supplied screenshot, I don't see any of the names $u$, $v$, $x$, or $y$ for scalars also being used as names for functions.

Comment: Also, use `\partial` if you want to get the symbol $\partial$.

Comment: Thank you @Hurkyl, I have updated the diagram and the text. Please let me know if it is still unclear. Lower case literals stand for variables and upper case literals stand for functions.

Answer (score 1):

The expressions $\frac{\mathrm{d}v}{\mathrm{d}u}$ and $\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\mathrm{d}v}$ are indeed meaningless because the differentials $\mathrm{d}u$ and ${\mathrm{d}v}$ are not ratios of one another.

But those are not the expressions appearing in the formulas.

When given a system of coordinates such as $\{ u, v \}$, the equations

$$ \frac{\partial v}{\partial u} = 0 = \frac{\partial u}{\partial v}$$

are basically (half of) the *definition* of the notation. For reductions to other familiar notions:

- $\frac{\partial}{\partial u}$ is notation that means to take the directional derivative in the direction where $v$ is held constant and $u$ increases with unit rate. That is, $\frac{\partial}{\partial u} = \nabla_{\vec{s}}$ where $\vec{s}$ is chosen to be the vector such that $\nabla_{\vec{s}} u = 1$ and $\nabla_{\vec{s}} v = 0$
- $\frac{\partial}{\partial u}$ is the linear operator on differential forms that sends $\mathrm{d}u \mapsto 1$ and $\mathrm{d}v \mapsto 0$. The notation $\frac{\partial z}{\partial u}$ means to apply $\frac{\partial}{\partial u}$ to the differential $\mathrm{d} z$.

---

Aside: do take care to note that despite only one of the two variables appearing in $\frac{\partial}{\partial u}$, the operation depends on the entire choice of coordinate system $\{ u, v \}$. If  $\{ u, x \}$ also happened to be a coordinate system, the operator $\frac{\partial}{\partial u}$ you would write for that coordinate system is different from the operator by the same name you would write for the $\{ u, v \}$ system.

If you ever find yourself in such a situation and still want to retain the use of this notation, you could do something like

$$ \left.\frac{\partial}{\partial u}\right|_{v \mathrm{\ const}} $$

to refer to the operator that is relative to the $\{ u, v \}$ coordinate system.